# SVN - What are all the benefits we have if we commit a huge files list in a single shot rather than multiple commits?

Tags: svn, file, commit, repository

I woud like to understand what are all the benefits we have if we commit a huge files list in a single shot rather than multiple commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the big advantages of Subversion over CVS is its ability to keep related changes as a single change set rather than a dispersed set of individual file changes. Let's say you're working on a new feature which involved a dozen files. Now, you're told that the change must be reverted.

If you used a system like CVS, those changes are treated as a dozen individual and independent changes. Tracking them all down can be quite difficult. You could use timestamps, but you'll still have to search your entire repository. You can try tagging your changes, but you still have to move across the entire repository looking for that change.

In Subversion, that change was a single change set. Backing on that change simply means backing out that single changeset.

Another advantage is that Subversion can do atomic changes on a change set. Imagine if you have 20 files that are all related to a single modification. Now, imagine in one of those files, someone did an update while you were testing your changes. In CVS, if you did a commit, 19 of those files would be committed, but not the last.

Now, your repository is in an untested and probably unstable state. In fact, there's a good chance that your software won't even build. Your instinct is to quickly do an update on that one file, and then run some rough tests, and commit that one file.

In Subversion, not one of the files you changed would be committed. The repository is still in a stable and tested state. You don't have to worry about the repository and can update that one file, and run a complete regression test before attempting to do your commit again.

---

So, in the answer to your question, should you commit all those files in one big list: It depends. Commit file changes as discrete change sets. It might be that all of those files changes you've made are not related to each other. In that case, feel free to make each one a separate change list. Don't worry about the revision number being *to high*. I never understood this concern since the revision number has no effect on the quality of your software.

Then again, if all of the changes are one set, make a single commit of your changes. The idea is if someone is trying to analyze a change, then can quickly see all of the files involved. A change could be a single feature, a bug number, or however you want to measure your change. The point is to make commit your changes in logical units.

Answer (score 2):

easier to see what files were related for the task,
e.g. possible to see which files were modified for performing the fix for bug #123

oh, and make sure you add the bug number in the commit comment, it makes life so much easier when you want to go back in time to see what you changed
e.g.
"hm, we fixed this bug about a year or two ago, strange that it was reopened, lets check the commit history what we did back then"
and then you simply search for the bug number and you find it in an instant.

and the other way around: in your bugtracking system, add a note which commit number that fixed the bug, makes life so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Size matters not.

One commit should cover one logical change that may or may not span over several files. If you combine several logical changes into one commit then it may be difficult later to find or revert one of those logical changes. If it's too late to separate changes into logical units then commit all at once and hope you'll not regret it.

Answer (score 0):

better for keeping Version number smaller, easier to track your changes ,

** leave comments when you commit, because you may forget why you did that commit